# Is passing a view for an interface frown upon?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mvvm, observer-pattern

Assume your model or view-model needs to display a message but it obviously doesn't want to access UI. So it implements an interface which has Notify(String) method.

Now whoever implements this interface can show the message and that object would typically be UI based class which would need to be passed to the model or view-model.

My question is, will it be frown upon to pass a UI object even though it's only being passed as interface?

I have illustrated this issue with a mock example.

```
  public interface INotify
    {
        void  Notify(String msg);
    }

    class Model
    {
        INotify _notify;

        public Model(INotify notify )
        {
            _notify = notify;
        }

        public void Add(int a, int b)
        {
            int result = a + b;

            _notify.Notify("The result is " + result.ToString());
        }

    }

    class View : INotify
    {
        public void Notify(String msg)
        {
            Console.Write("I am the view, I received this: ");
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            View view = new View();
            Model model = new Model(view);

            model.Add(4, 7);
        }
    }
```

The result is as expected, the key point is that it's printed from the view.

> I am the view, I received this: The result is 11
>   Press any key to continue . . .

In the real world, the `view` class would be a full blown UI class like windows form or wpf etc but it's only being passed in place for an interface that it implements. Will this be frown upon why the view is being passed as an interface that it implements?

If it will be frown upon, isn't this exactly the job of interface though? In this case, it's derived class will be expected to be some kind of UI class to show the message after all and it will have a lot of other things.

I am trying to understand the practical uses of interfaces and also solve a problem with it when occasionally model view in MVVC or MVVM might want to display a message.

The other variation is to implement full observer pattern but in my case, the model or view-model needs to display message in only in one window (never in multiple) so passing that view for interface logically makes sense.

Comment: I see no problem with `INotify` in a model because in many respects its the same as having a logging interface in a model - both output something and the fact that one may send the output to disk rather than to a screen is neither here nor there for a decoupled interface.  In WPF/MVVM, its a common problem where to place say that load-from-database or WCF client code the answer usually being injected services into the VM.  So with that precedent you can inject some "UI Service" into your VM that can furfill UI requests on your behalf

Comment: @MickyD That makes me feel better. The goal is always that model-view shouldn't  need view but when its unavoidable or porting legacy code, a model-view may want to report an error or ask user a yes/no question, this makes a lot of sense. It still doesn't know about view but the view does get passed as interface, which to me sound like good use of interface but not sure if this might be bad thing for any reason or violate MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this would be a problem at all, as long as it doesn't affect performance in a bad way that is notable or that it looks strange later on in the project when you start to add more and more on the GUI, etc.